# Main site content stuck under left navigation menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is my first time really trying to design something on my own. I'm using the Underscores Wordpress base theme. I have the basics of my main menu pretty much figured out, but my main site content is stuck under it. The menu should be on the left and the content to the right of it.

Link:

http://robkaufmanshow.com/strictlyecw/?page_id=2

Code of menu;

```
.main-navigation {
clear: both;
display: block;
width: 170px;
float: left;
background-image: url('http://robkaufmanshow.com/strictlyecw/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/menubg.png');
}
.main-navigation ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
.main-navigation a {
font-family: chiller;
font-size: 18px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 2px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 155px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
display: none;
float: left;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 1.5em;
z-index: 99999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
left: 100%;
top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
width: 170px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a {
background-image: url('http://robkaufmanshow.com/strictlyecw/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/menubg02.png');
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
.main-navigation .current_page_item a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item a {
}
/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    display: none;
}
}
.site-main [class*="navigation"] {
margin: 0 0 1.5em;
overflow: hidden;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next {
float: right;
text-align: right;
width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
#masthead{
   float:left;
}
```

For future purposes, use  for side menus. Header is supposed to be for headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
#site-navigation{
float:left;
clear:none;
}

#main{
float:left;
clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Using masthead float left almost had the desired effect, but my Wordpress comments section was still stuck under the menu.

I'm not really sure where to add the float left clear none and float left clear left, though. Could you take a look at my CSS source and identify that? I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: Remove your fixed position from #sidebar. You can't use positioning and floats at the same time.